# Wall jumping height decreases with each jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Solved - I ended up removing `playerController.SimpleMove` and having `playerController.Move` control all the player's movement.

So I have been trying to make my character wall jump between to walls. I've been able to make it work however, after each successful wall jump the height of the next jump decreases. This gets to the point where it starts wall jumping downwards. I have no idea why it does this. Before each time pressing the space bar, I am resetting the movement Vector3's to zero and then reapplying the correct values to the jump. I have even gone through the console to look at the vertical changes and neither moveDirection and moveAmount get a large enough value change to make this happen.

Because I am just trying this out, below is all the code that is affecting the player.

```
public float rotateSpeed = 3.0f;
public float walkSpeed = 5.0f;
public float runSpeed = 15.0f;
public float jumpSpeed = 10.0f;
public float acceleration = .05f;

public bool running = false;
public bool jumping = false;
public bool falling = false;
public bool onWall = false;
public bool wallJumping = false;
public bool stay = false;

private CharacterController playerController;
private Animator playerAnimator;
private float speed;
private Vector3 moveAmount;
private float animationSpeed;

private float currentSpeed;
private float targetSpeed;
private float moveSpeed;

float gravity = 10f;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    playerController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed, 0);
if (onWall)
    {
        playerAnimator.SetBool("Wall Holding", true);
        jumping = false;
    }
    else
    {
        playerAnimator.SetBool("Wall Holding", false);
    }

    if (stay)
    {
        moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        moveAmount = Vector3.zero;
    }

    #region Player Controls
    if (Input.GetButton("Vertical") && !wallJumping)
    {
        moveSpeed = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed;
        moveAmount = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    }
    else
    {
        moveSpeed = 0;
        moveAmount = Vector3.zero;
    }

    if (playerController.isGrounded){
        moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        jumping = false;
        wallJumping = false;
        onWall = false;
        stay = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!stay)
            onWall = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (playerController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            jumping = true;
        }
        else if (onWall)
        {
            moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
            moveAmount = Vector3.zero;
            wallJumping = true;
            moveDirection += transform.forward * jumpSpeed * 2f;
            moveDirection += transform.up * jumpSpeed * 2f;
            stay = false;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        if (playerAnimator.GetBool("fight"))
        {
            playerAnimator.SetBool("fight", false);
        }
        else
        {
            playerAnimator.SetBool("fight", true);
        }
    }
    #endregion Player Controls

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    Debug.Log(moveDirection.x);
    targetSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
    currentSpeed = SpeedFactor(targetSpeed, currentSpeed, acceleration);

    if (currentSpeed > walkSpeed)
        running = true;
    else
        running = false;

    playerAnimator.SetFloat("movespeed", currentSpeed);

    if (!stay)
    {
        playerController.SimpleMove(currentSpeed * moveAmount);
        playerController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

private float SpeedFactor (float targetSpeed, float currentSpeed, float dilation) {
    if ( currentSpeed < targetSpeed) {
        currentSpeed += dilation;
        if ( currentSpeed > targetSpeed) {
            currentSpeed = targetSpeed;
        }
    }
    else if ( currentSpeed > targetSpeed) {
        currentSpeed -= dilation;
        if ( currentSpeed < targetSpeed) {
            currentSpeed = targetSpeed;
        }
    }
    return currentSpeed;
}

void OnControllerColliderHit (ControllerColliderHit hit) {
    if (hit.gameObject.tag == "JumpingWall" && !playerController.isGrounded && !onWall && (jumping || wallJumping))
    {
        onWall = true;
        transform.Rotate(0,180,0);
        stay = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation is that `transform.forward` and/or `transform.up` vectors begin to diverge from your expectations over time. This would explain how it even seems to be jumping "backwards" eventually when you apply the lines below. Are you sure these vectors are oriented as you expect after the jumper collides with a wall (prior to the next jump)?

```
moveDirection += transform.forward * jumpSpeed * 2f;
moveDirection += transform.up * jumpSpeed * 2f;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As to your question, yes I am fairly sure they are. I even had both lines set to = instead of += and the same results happened. I have done some further testing and it seems that height seems to be a factor to the backwards jumping, but again I have no idea why it would be a thing.

Comment: The `+=` vs `=` should not make a difference because you zeroed `moveDirection` just prior to those two assignments. You could try replacing `moveDirection += transform.up * jumpSpeed * 2f;` with `moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed * 2f;` (the last assignment statement) to see what difference it makes. The `.y` vector should be invariant, whereas the `transform.up` vector will depend on jumper's orientation. I would log / examine **all 3** components of `moveDirection` after these 2 assignment statements. Then you will see how the forces were assigned to each invariant 3D vector direction (x, y, z).

Comment: Thanks for a the help you provided. But I managed to fix it by removing playerController.SimpleMove. I discovered that it was influencing the height. I really should have removed it earlier on but I had trouble in doing so. Oh, and your line change didn't make a difference to the problem either. Thanks again though.